What path in WSL2 maps to the current windows user directory?
Is there a path variable (not a command, not a custom variable I need to create) in WSL2 that maps to the current user's profile directory (e.g. %USERPROFILE%), but is generic for Windows/Mac devices?
I am trying to configure volumes in a docker-compose file that needs to be generic and cross-platform, but the tilde (~) I had used in the past appears to map to a different WSL2-only home directory, not my current user's %USERPROFILE% directory.
This is what I want, but it's the wrong user directory:
volumes:
  - ~/microsoft/UserSecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
  - ~/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https/

This works, but it's not generic for other developers:
volumes:
  - /mnt/c/Users/MyUser/microsoft/UserSecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
  - /mnt/c/Users/MyUser/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https/

Everything I found stated to use commands/variables to determine/access the current user's app data directory, but that's not feasible in this context and I really don't want to have to define yet another variable developers have to use.
Apologies if this is already answered, I'm a bit new to WSL and I'm pretty sure the ~ path used to map to the actual windows user directory since the docker compose file was working a couple years ago when it was written using ~ as the home path.
